# File monitoring program detection failure in Java

Tags: java

There will be a directory monitoring function in my program for monitoring any new file coming to that dedicated directory.If there's any new file reach that folder, it's will trigger the API call and deliver the file to remote server via post method. For my testing purpose, I will use copy and paste the file into my testing directory. But when I check my server, I able to saw that at least 5 similar file had reached my server within same timestamp but I just copy one file to my testing directory. After the file had sent to the remote server, it's will move the file into another directory but before the file being move to another directory, there will be some JSON data processing return by the remote server for checking which is the most suitable folder to move the file. 
 This is some portion of my source code

```
try(WatchService svc = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService()) 
        {
            Map<WatchKey, Path> keyMap = new HashMap<>();
            Path path = Paths.get("C://REST API//SentFile"); //register watch event for any new file 
            keyMap.put(path.register(svc,
                    StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE,
                    StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE,
                    StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY),
                    path);

            WatchKey wk ;
            do 
            {
                Thread.sleep(10);   //halt the program for a while 
                wk = svc.take();
                Path dir = keyMap.get(wk);
                for(WatchEvent<?> event : wk.pollEvents())
                {
                    WatchEvent.Kind<?> type = event.kind();
                    Path fileName = (Path)event.context();
                    System.out.println(" The new file :"+fileName);  //print the new file name 
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.27:8008/file");  //remote API URL 
                    String ConvertFile = String.valueOf(fileName); 
                    String filepath = "C://REST API//SentFile//";
                    String file = filepath.concat(ConvertFile);  // the file directory 
                    FileBody bin = new FileBody(new File(file));  // take the file from directory 
                    HttpEntity reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()  // build require argument 
                               .addPart("display_name", bin)
                               .build();
                    post.addHeader("filename", ConvertFile);  
                    post.setEntity(reqEntity);  // send via post method 
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);  // receice response from remote server 
                    Thread.sleep(6);  //halt the program for a while for remote processing 
                    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                    StringBuffer bf = new StringBuffer();
                    String line = "";
                  while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) 
                    {
                      bf.append(line); 
                    } 
                   JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(bf.toString());   //read the data from remote response 
                   String ID = obj.getString("data_id");  
                   System.out.println("The data id from server :" +ID);  //display the ID 
                  FileDetect fd = new FileDetect();
                  fd.send(ID);  //send the ID for another API call
```

This is my send() method source code

```
private void send(String data_ID) throws IOException, JSONException, InterruptedException 
    {
     System.out.println("The Data ID is :" + data_ID);  //display ID after the send()
      String Url = "http://192.168.0.27:8008/file/";
      String FinalURL = Url.concat(data_ID);
      System.out.println("URL is : " + FinalURL);  // the remote API URL 
      URL theUrl = new URL (FinalURL);
      HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) theUrl.openConnection();  //API call
      con.setRequestMethod("GET");
      con.connect();
      int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
      if(responseCode == 200)
      {
      try
       {
         InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
         BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(is));
         StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
         String data = "" ; 
         while((data = read.readLine() ) != null )
         {
             buffer.append(data);
         }

         String JsonData = buffer.toString();
         JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(JsonData);
         JSONObject scArr = jobj.getJSONObject("scan_results"); 
         JSONObject fileInfo = jobj.getJSONObject("file_info");
         int scan_result = scArr.getInt("scan_all_result_i");
         String fileName = fileInfo.getString("display_name");
         System.out.println("The file name :" + fileName);   //display JSON data from server 
         System.out.println("The scan result : " +scan_result );  //display JSON data from server 
         if(scan_result == 0 )   //move the file base on result
         {
             String sour1 = "C://REST API//SentFile//";
             String sourPath = sour1.concat(fileName);
           try
            {
          Path sour = Paths.get(sourPath);
          Path Dest = Paths.get("C://Users//user//Documents//no_thread");
          System.out.println("Start to copy no_thread file");
          Files.move(sour, Dest.resolve(sour.getFileName()));
          System.out.println("Completed");
            }
           catch (IOException e)
           {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
         }
         else if(scan_result == 1 )  //move the file base on result 
         {
           String sour1 = "C://REST API//SentFile//";
           String sourPath = sour1.concat(fileName);
           try
            {
            Path sour = Paths.get(sourPath);
            Path Dest = Paths.get("C://Users//user//Documents//infected");
            System.out.println("Start to copy infected file");
            Files.move(sour, Dest.resolve(sour.getFileName()));
            System.out.println("Completed");
            }
           catch (IOException e)
           {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
         }   
    }
      finally
      {
          System.out.print("No Error");
      }
  } 
   Thread.sleep(10);
 } 
}
```

This is the debugging statement display in my compiler

```
 The new file :eicar.com.txt
The data id from server :86ade39d4b7243188245bc8537242fa4
The Data ID is :86ade39d4b7243188245bc8537242fa4
URL is : http://192.168.0.27:8008/file/86ade39d4b7243188245bc8537242fa4
The file name :eicar.com.txt
The scan result : 1
Start to copy infected file
Completed
No Error 
The new file :eicar.com.txt
Dec 03, 2016 5:37:19 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.io.FileNotFoundException) caught when processing request: C:\REST API\SentFile\eicar.com.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
Dec 03, 2016 5:37:19 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector execute
INFO: Retrying request
Dec 03, 2016 5:37:19 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.io.FileNotFoundException) caught when processing request: C:\REST API\SentFile\eicar.com.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
Dec 03, 2016 5:37:19 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector execute
INFO: Retrying request
Dec 03, 2016 5:37:19 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.io.FileNotFoundException) caught when processing request: C:\REST API\SentFile\eicar.com.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
Dec 03, 2016 5:37:19 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector execute
INFO: Retrying request
Problem io  in somewhere
```

From the compiler display, it's seen all good from the beginning but "The new file : eicar.com.txt" display second time after the "No error" print statement, I had program that the file will move to another directory before the "No Error" print statement display, but I don't know why it's able to detect eicar.com.txt still a new file in my directory, I put **thread.sleep()** in my program but it's fail to function as expected

Answer (score 0):

You need to `reset` your `WatchKey` before you can `take` again:

```
wk = svc.take();
//Whatever you need to do here
wk.reset();
```

Comment: I had reset my watch key at the end of the do loop, is it the correct place to reset the watch key ?

Comment: but if I put it on do{......}while(wk.reset()); ,I am getting the print statement "The new file :eicar.com.txt" twice. The first one should be correct but after some processing on the file, the file should be move away from my folder, but I am not sure why the second "The new file :eicar.com.txt" still appear in the compiler

Comment: The processing of the file will being the send() method